# Where is a good place I can discuss the details about web development?

Tags: discussion, site-rec

I'm getting back into web development and a lot has changed. I was redirected here. Is this the place I can ask about web development processes, tools, problems and solutions? Thanks

Comment: You could always read existing questions for the answers to make your own mind up. Also see the StackOverflow link at the bottom.  However, this is not a programming chat site. Ask a focussed question for things you need, someone will answer. Vague or general questions will end up closed.

Comment: One of my questions is how are people testing that their website looks correct in the major browsers. Is that ok to ask here?

Comment: SQA.SE's [cross-browser-testing](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-browser-testing) tag might be of interest.

Comment: While some questions may be on topic here it sounds like you are more looking for more general info (which would be closed as too broad or for other reasons). You could start  to use the chat rooms here (or the web related ones on StackOverflow since you have enough reputation. Or maybe have a look at reddits /r/webdev subreddit where you can have open discussions about mostly anything.

Comment: Recommended: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in).